# How to start map application on iPhone from objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I develop app for IOS 6.
I want to run maps application and pass it start and destination so I can navigate user.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    NSString *coordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f", ...];

    [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: coordinates]];
```

I thought that this code will open google maps in browser on simulator, and maps app on device, but on the device it runs browser google map.
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not aware, Apple no longer uses Google maps so you have to use their new URL scheme for the Apple maps.
(Note: if you're supporting iOS 5, then you should use both. The google maps scheme and apple maps)

Here is an example query `http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino`

Here is the documentation for it: [Apple Maps URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you have an MKPlacemark object:

```
// placemark is your MKPlacemark object
MKMapItem* destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];

if([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:)])
{
   // Using iOS6 native maps app
   [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];      
}
else
{
   // Using iOS5 which has the Google Maps application
   NSString *currentLocation = @"Current%20Location";
   NSString *routeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@saddr=%@&daddr=%@", kMapsBaseUrl, currentLocation, address.mapAddress];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:routeString]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use on iOS 8.

First I try to open the url @"comgooglemaps://", if it works this means that they installed the google maps app, so then I can open the app.

If it doesn't work then the app isn't there, just open google maps in Safari.

In both cases it passes the query `q=London`.

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]){ //open google maps app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?q=London"]];
}
else{ //open browser 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)openAddressOnNativeMapApp{
NSString *addressOnMap = @"cupertino";  //place name
NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@",addressOnMap];
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

}

For More Info visit [Apple Doc for open native map App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)